# Unable to save username and password in firefox browser

Tags: reactjs, firefox, redux, redux-form

I have a login form where the user can enter a username and password.
I am able to save username and password in chrome browser. In case of Firefox browser, I am not able to save username and password. (react 16.2.0)

Comment: Please read about [Creating a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and please describe in particular what do you mean by: _save username and password_

Comment: Please provide more information or code snippets in order for someone to be able to help you. Best Regards.